# Increment value of textinput with jquery like spinner

Tags: jquery, onclick, spinner, increment

Trying to create a simple spinner effect with Jquery, i.e. two buttons (up & down) with a text field.  The upbutton increases the value while the down button decreses the value.  increment steps + or - 1.

Any suggestions as ui.spinner is most def. not working and I am new to jquery.  musty be something like 
`$(#up).click (function ( /*SOMETHING GOES IN HERE but what?*/ ))` and likewise for #down. both to set adjust the input text field say id #test as above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Russell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var el = $('#test');
  function change( amt ) {
    el.val( parseInt( el.val(), 10 ) + amt );
  }

  $('#up').click( function() {
    change( 1 );
  } );
  $('#down').click( function() {
    change( -1 );
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks thenduks works a treat, but ummm... being stupid now forgot to add something, how to go up/down a <ul><li> list in the same way - sorry

Comment: @russel: Not sure what you mean... "go" up/down a list?

Comment: It would be trivial to make this work with multiple on a page. Start by changing the `#up` and `#down` id's to `.up` and `.down`, instead of just `change(1)` and using `el` in the function, you can find and then pass the target element along too... Easy.

Answer (score 9):

Demo: http://jsbin.com/akiki

```
<button id="inc">+</button>
<button id="dec">-</button>
<input type="text" name="qty" value="0" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#inc").click(function(){
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    $("#dec").click(function(){
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this demo - I have found that this works the best of all the ones I've tried

Especially if you are using jquery ui themes

http://btburnett.com/spinner/example/example.html

Answer (score 0):

With the base code by @rfunduk I created this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var el = $('#quantity_wanted');

    function change( amt ) {

        if (el.val() == '') {
            var newValue = 1;
        } else {
            var newValue = parseInt( el.val(), 10 ) + amt;
        }

        if (newValue > 0) {
            el.val( newValue );
        }

    }

    $('#cart_quantity_up').click( function() {
        change( 1 );
    } );

    $('#cart_quantity_down').click( function() {
        change( -1 );
    } );
} );
```