# Javascript/jquery iframe next/previous navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have like a hundred of html files with names 2.html, 4.html, 6.html, 8.html etc. and i want to make simple "next/prev" navigation with iframe. If user press "next" - html in iframe changes from 2.html to 4.html. Press "prev" - from 4 to 2.

Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244862/jquery-plus-minus-incrementer) solution with increments 2 and -2, but it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var page = 2;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').click(function(){
        page += 2;
        $('iframe').attr('src', './'+page+'.html');
    });
    $('#previous').click(function(){
        page -= 2;
        $('iframe').attr('src', './'+page+'.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, only one question - how to make limits? 0 and, for example, 100? Because it goes to infinity and negative.

Comment: You can check the page iterator.  after page += 2, add: if(page>upperLimit){page=2;}   of course you'll have to create an upperLimit variable.