# How to change the value with +/- , but based on a predetermined array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to learn some javascript, and need some help with this.

have an array:

```
var my_nrs = [2.3, 2.8, 3.3, 4.6]
```

an input field with a default value from previous array:

```
<input type=text size=5 id='the_nr' name='the_nr' value='2.8'>
```

What I want to accomplish is change the value of that input but only with the values from the array **'my_nrs'**.

So i need to get the *index* of **'the_nr'** in **'my_nrs'** and by pressing the button's **'+ -'** travel in the array **'my_nrs'** and populate the input with that, right?

I have been looking in this page [Jquery Plus/Minus...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244862/jquery-plus-minus-incrementer) but noting related to get the values from an array by index...

Can anyone help me to code this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a <select /> instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
var nr = $('#the_nr'), my_nrs = [2.3, 2.8, 3.3, 4.6];

$('#p').click(function(){
   var cv = nr.val();
   var pos = my_nrs.indexOf( Number(cv) ) + 1; //zero-based
   var len = my_nrs.length;
   if (pos >= len) return false;
   else nr.val( my_nrs[pos] );
});

$('#m').click(function(){
   var cv = nr.val();
   var pos = my_nrs.indexOf( Number(cv) ); //zero-based
   if (pos < 1) return false;
   else nr.val( my_nrs[pos-1] );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type=text size=5 id='the_nr' name='the_nr' value='2.8'><br>
<button id="p">Plus</button>
<button id="m">Minus</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, it's perfect and easy to understand! ;)

Comment: @user5617880 See [this update](https://jsfiddle.net/dpsosuhk/1/) to Özgür Ersil's below solution. That might be correct solution for your application. *Interesting side-note: In the jsFiddle, observe what happens when you change `++index` to `index++` (interesting, yes?)*

Answer (score 1):

use increment script with click actions

```
var my_nrs = [2.3, 2.8, 3.3, 4.6];
var index = 0;


$(".plus").click(function(){
    if(index < my_nrs.length - 1){

    index++;
    $('#the_nr').val(my_nrs[index]) ;

  }
})

$(".minus").click(function(){
        if(index > 0 ){
    index--;
    $('#the_nr').val( my_nrs[index] ); 

  }
})
```

here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dpsosuhk/)

Comment: Thanks for help! So easy now that I see the solution! ;)

Comment: Well done gibberish! unfortunately I can't vote to everyone. thanks again to both of you ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#the_tr').val( my_nrs[0] );
```

Whats wrong with that? You can use

```
$('#the_tr').data('index', 0)
```

To set the index, and the same but without the last parameter to fetch it.

Edit: Check this out -> https://jsfiddle.net/uus7Lo49/

Comment: thanks for you help, but the list it's more big than the sample, so "going back" it's really helpful and desired ;)