# HTML5 input type number not working in firefox

Tags: html, forms

I am using `HTML5 input type=number`. Its working perfectly in Chrome browser, but its not working in Firefox and IE9.

I want to increment the quantity by `one` i.e. `step=1` and also I have set `min=1`.

I am using the following code:

```
<form action="" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1"  name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>     
</form>
```

Is there any patch or hack to make it work in Firefox and IE9. Or else, what could be the possible solution for that.

Comment: a list of web forms (and others) HTML5 polyfills: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms - also check caniuse.com for cross-browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/input-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The min attribute of the  tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Firefox.

Note: The min attribute will not work for dates and time in Internet Explorer 10, since IE 10 does not support these input types.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Comment: Then what will be best solution to implement `increment` and `decrement` text value by 1. In general, I want to user-friendly buttons for `Quantity`.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript in this project?  If so, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183226/increment-a-number-by-clicking-onto-a-button  and its Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nTmu7/2/

Answer (score 12):

It is not supported in firefox or internet explorer, except for version 11 which has partial support. See [this comparison matrix](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ff22/ie11/chrome28.html).

You can use the [number polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill) shim to get support for unsupported browsers.

Answer (score 9):

Alternately, you can use a textfield with a `pattern=""` attribute. Although it **doesn't** have the up and down buttons, it **does** validate for having the correct values:

```
<input type="text"
       name="quantity"
       pattern="[1-9]"
       value="1"
       required
       title="Qty"
       class="input-text qty text"
/>
```

You can alter the pattern to your quantity wishes, it is now set for a value ranging from **1** to **9**. Also you can add up/down buttons with JS/jQuery that have hotkeys bound to them for a more number-field-like feel.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of this!  Note: The pattern attribute of the <input> tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.  But luckily IE9 and Safari support the number type so it's a non issue.

Answer (score 5):

For React I have used a simple and clean implementation to forbid letters in Firefox/Safari/Chrome etc...

`<input type="number" onKeyDown={(event) => checkIfNumber(event)} />`

```
checkIfNumber(event) {

   /**
    * Allowing: Integers | Backspace | Tab | Delete | Left & Right arrow keys
    **/

   const regex = new RegExp(/(^\d*$)|(Backspace|Tab|Delete|ArrowLeft|ArrowRight)/);
        
   return !event.key.match(regex) && event.preventDefault();
}
```

Allowing more keys:

By logging the `event.key` in the console you are able to check the actual value of the pressed key while then adding it to the `regex` using a pipe `|` symbol.

Keep in mind that this solution only allows `Integers`, if you want to allow `floating` numbers(decimals) use the following `regex` pattern

`regex = new RegExp(/(^\d*\.?\d*$)|(Backspace|Tab|Delete|ArrowLeft|ArrowRight)/)`

You can build and check your regex pattern here:

- https://regex101.com/

Comment: I've added on my end the ArrowUp and ArrowDown keys, but it's a good solution!

Answer (score 3):

The input type `number` is not supported yet in Firefox or IE9 (almost in IE10), so it will revert to input type `text`.

See [this compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html).

There's really no need for a "patch or hack" - a regular input field will work just fine. That's why it reverts to a text field. Whether or not it displays as an actual number field to the end-user is just a *bonus* to make it slightly more convenient. You should still be doing server-side checks on whatever value is sent to you, so allowing a user to just type in a number when their browser doesn't support the number type shouldn't harm anything.

Comment: Is this good to use [Add (+/-) Button Number Incrementers](http://css-tricks.com/number-increment-buttons/) for `Quantity` incrementers?

Comment: This is true, but it really makes a difference for mobile browsers; because those that support it will render a different keypad for number fields.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: If a mobile browser supports it though, it won't revert to a text field...

Comment: @MohitBhansali: You can do that, but I'd make sure they *only* show up when the browser doesn't support the number field by default.

Answer (score 3):

To allow only number and points to be written in an input we have to get the value of the pressed key and compare it with a REGEX (test() method), otherwise the event isn't executed.

```
const input = document.getElementById("numberInput");    

input.addEventListener("keypress", e => {

    // If the input is empty and the key pressed is "0" nothing is printed
    if (!e.target.value && e.key == 0) {

        e.preventDefault();

    } else {

        // If the key pressed is not a number or a period, nothing is printed
        if (!/[0-9.]/.test(keyValue)) {

            e.preventDefault();

        }

    }

}
```

Also I created a function that allows writing a maximum of three whole numbers and two decimal numbers.
I hope it helps you.

I usually post information that has helped me or some solutions on my twitter ([@PabloAndresValC](https://twitter.com/PabloAndresValC))

```
input.addEventListener("keypress", e => {

    const keyValue = e.key;

    // If the input is empty and the key pressed is "0" nothing is printed
    if (!e.target.value && keyValue == 0) {

        e.preventDefault();

    } else {
        // If the key pressed is not a number or a period, nothing is printed
        if (!/[0-9.]/.test(keyValue)) {

            e.preventDefault();

        } else {
            // If the number has one or two whole numbers and a point, another 
            // point won't be printed
            if (/[0-9]{1,2}[.]/.test(e.target.value) && keyValue == ".") {

                e.preventDefault();

            } 
             // If the number has one or two whole numbers and a point
            else if (/[0-9]{1,2}[.]/.test(e.target.value)) {
                // We can write up to two more numbers after the point
                if (/[0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{2}/.test(e.target.value)) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                }

            } 
            // If there are 3 numbers and we press another, a point 
            // will be printed automatically
            // And we can write up to two more numbers after the point
            else if (/[0-9]{3}/.test(e.target.value) && keyValue != ".") {

                    e.target.value += ".";

                if (/[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{2}/.test(e.target.value)) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                }

            }

        }
        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported.

You can use javascript for the same result if you really need it.

There are lot of examples :
[Increment value of textinput with jquery like spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064165/increment-value-of-textinput-with-jquery-like-spinner)

Answer (score 2):

I am using firefox, I had the same issue developing my input type number typing characters and spaces etc...
anyway I am using angular 2 in this example, it's almost similar to JavaScript, so you can use this code in every case :
here is the html :

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="qte" type="number"  min="1" max="30" step="1" [(ngModel)]="numberVoucher"
     (keypress)="FilterInput($event)" />
```

here is the function FilterInput :

```
FilterInput(event: any) {
        let numberEntered = false;
        if ((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40)) { //input number entered or one of the 4 directtion up, down, left and right
            //console.log('input number entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
            numberEntered = true;
        }
        else {
            //input command entered of delete, backspace or one of the 4 directtion up, down, left and right
            if ((event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) || event.keyCode == 46 || event.which == 8) {
                //console.log('input command entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
            }
            else {
                //console.log('input not number entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        // input is not impty
        if (this.validForm) {
            // a number was typed
            if (numberEntered) {
                let newNumber = parseInt(this.numberVoucher + '' + String.fromCharCode(event.which));
                console.log('new number : ' + newNumber);
                // checking the condition of max value
                if ((newNumber <= 30 && newNumber >= 1) || Number.isNaN(newNumber)) {
                    console.log('valid number : ' + newNumber);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('max value will not be valid');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            // command of delete or backspace was types
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.which == 8) {
                if (this.numberVoucher >= 1 && this.numberVoucher <= 9) {
                    console.log('min value will not be valid');
                    this.numberVoucher = 1;
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    this.validForm = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // input is empty
        else {
            console.log('this.validForm = true');
            this.validForm = false;
        }
    };
```

in this function I had to just let the keypress of numbers, direction, deletes enter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best practice in my previous projects experience.
This solution worked on Firefox, Safari and other not support input[type=number] realized browsers.

```js
document.querySelector('#number-input').addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
!/(^\d*\.?\d*$)|(Backspace|Control|Meta|a)/.test(evt.key) && evt.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<html>
   <input type="number" id="number-input"/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 89.0 solves this problem.

Comment: why? add some explanation please

Comment: Could you provide a changelog link of the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    @keypress="getMobileNumber($event)"
    />              
//Function 
function:getMobileNumber(e){
    let char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // Get the character
    if (/^[0-9]*$/.test(char)) return true;
    // Match with regex
    else e.preventDefault(); // If not match, don't add to input text
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="inpNum(event)" />

function inpNum(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  if (!charStr.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="funcname(event)" />

function funcname(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  if (!charStr.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

this worked for me