# angular js type number not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please check this code.

```
   <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="value"
                     min="0" max="99" required>
```

I am getting only a text field in firefox for the above code and in google chrome its working fine .

```
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      Number: <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="value"
                     min="0" max="99" required>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
        Not valid number!</span>
      <tt>value = {{value}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
     </form>
```

Comment: This is not supported by Firefox. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976393/html5-input-type-number-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: @Chandermani thanks.. is there any other way or tag instead of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox doesn't seem to support the `type="number"`, however, angular does polyfill Firefox so that the `type="number"` input field functions correctly (in terms of validation etc) in Firefox.

So, the code that you have provided should validate correctly in Firefox.

However, you don't see the little arrows like you might see in Chrome:

[image]

To get this effect in Firefox you can use the [input number polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill).

[image]

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aFHg8x?p=preview) showing this polyfill in action.