# Number input field loses focus on validation change

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

When the validation state changes from invalid to valid, the current input field loses its focus on Firefox ([Minimum working example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoeni/D7HN2/)):

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in list track by $index">
    <ng-form name='innerform'>
        <input name="id" type="number" ng-model="elem.id" required/>
        <div ng-if="innerform.id.$error.required">Required!</div>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

This behaviour seems to happen in **Firefox only** and **only with an input field of type 'number'**. Change that to "text" or use Chrome and it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong here or is that a bug in AngularJS or FireFox?

Comment: I don't have any problem, I tried with Chrome and Firefox, which browser version are you using ?

Comment: Yep, it loses, firefox for mac. Might be a bug..

Comment: Firefox 30 and 31 on Win7. Chrome 36.0 works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Firefox when inserting a block into an inline element, not in AngularJS.
A fix for upcoming FF versions is on the way already: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1045270

Meanwhile a good workaround was proposed by caitp on https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8365:

> Add a style="display: block;" or style="display: inline-block;" (or just add these in a CSS file or style tag) for the affected elements (in the case of the original issue, ng-form) --- or alternatively, use the ng-form attribute on a block element.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occuring mainly because of type="number". Change it to type="email" or other it works fine.

Firefox doesn't seem to support the type="number", however, angular does polyfill Firefox so that the type="number" input field functions correctly (in terms of validation etc) in Firefox.

For make to work it use input number polyfill. [SEE HERE](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill)

[SEE RELATED QUESTION HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901186/angular-js-type-number-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: That's very helpful to understand, thank you. But even with the additional polyfill loaded it's still losing focus. But I'll just replace the number fields with text fields for a start.

Comment: I didn't realize the number validations (min, max) are bound to type="number", so i would lose all my number validations when converting to "text" :-(
So I will have to fix losing the focus...
I don't care about working up/down buttons etc

Comment: Its too difficult to point out the problem.According to me put input type="text" and do all the validation externally.Also read http://blakeembrey.com/articles/angular-js-number-validation-bug/

Comment: There seems to be lot of problem with type="number" in different browser.Check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395188/angular-validate-input-type-number

Comment: I just opened a ticket for AngularJS: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8365

Comment: Thanks.This will help me too