# Input type number validation Firefox/AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have version of angular `1.4.4`

And when I insert a number to `input type="number"` like `5.5` I have a validation problem... If I insert a number like `5` or `5,5` I haven't got problem.

Why?
Only in Firefox, in Chrome it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality in firefox also.
Please refer below link.
[angular js type number not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901186/angular-js-type-number-not-working-in-firefox)