# In javascript, obj.type always reports as text for HTML5 types

Tags: javascript, html

Despite the fact the I put `type="number"` (or any other HTML5 supported types), Firefox reports the type as `text`. What can I do to get around this?

**Example**

```
<input type="number" id="test"/>
<input type="button" onclick="window.alert(document.getElementById('test').type)" value="test"/>
```

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html

Comment: http://caniuse.com/input-number

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 input type number not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976393/html5-input-type-number-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: @Ian — The question is why the type property doesn't report "number", not why Firefox renders it as a text input.

Comment: @Quentin And I've posted stuff related to it. You've posted an answer for the question with much more detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `number` is supported by HTML 5, it *isn't* supported by Firefox (stable, at the time of writing) which sets the `type` property to the *actual* type when it creates the element. (By specification, unknown types are treated as "text").

If you want to get the attribute value instead, then use `getAttribute('type')` (where Firefox will tell you whatever has been entered in the type attribute without conversion).

Comment: The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility) claims that Firefox supports `type="number"` as of version 28.0. (I have an earlier version, so I can't test that)

Comment: @RussellZahniser - Current stable is 27, but I'll mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `getAttribute('type')` on that element instead.