# How can i save decimal numbers to save in point numbers

Tags: vue.js, cross-browser

I am working on a Vue project. I need to save variables in decimal numbers using point numbers.
for Ex: if I use 23,5 automatically this should be saved as 23.5
in Chrome it works well, but Firefox and other browsers doesn't change it to point numbers.

```js
function school (ind){
     this['School Name'] = "",
     this['Subject 1'] = "56.6",
     this['Subject 2'] = "",
     this['Subject 3'] = ""
    }

    var Vue1 = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
      schoolinfo: []
     },
     methods: {   
      addSchool: function(){
       this.add_School++;
       var len = this.schoolinfo.length;
       var newSchool = new school(this.add_School);
       this.schoolinfo.push(newSchool);
      } 
     }
    })



    function exportSchool() {
     
     var school_to_export = { 'school Info': data_Vue.schoolinfo };
      console.log( JSON.stringify(school_to_export));   
    }

    function init() {

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <body onload="init();">   
      <div id='app'>     
       <div>
        <button v-on:click="addSchool(); "> Add new School</button>
        <table  v-if="schoolinfo.length > 0">
         <tr>
          <td>School Name</td>
          <td>Subject 1</td>
          <td>Subject 2</td>
          <td>Subject 3</td>
         </tr>
         
         <tr v-for='(school, index) in schoolinfo' >
          <td> <input v-model="school['School Name']"> </td>
          <td> <input type="number" v-model.number="school['Subject 1']"> </td>
          <td> <input type="number" v-model.number="school['Subject 2']"> </td>
          <td> <input type="number" v-model.number="school['Subject 3']"> </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       
       <button onclick="exportSchool()" >clicl to see in Console</button>
      
     </body>
```

Firefox and other browsers don't change comma to point decimal. Chrome change from comma to point decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `v-model.number`?

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="school['School Name']">
```

You can find more information about `.number` in [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
decimal numbers are getting rounded. For ex. 34.3 saves to 34 and 34.6 saves to 35 in both firefox and chrome. It's good. But no rounded values!

Comment: Can you try adding `type="number"` to the input?

Comment: I edited the code in my post. Please try it in chrome and don't bother about some Vue error. You could see the school info in console. 
In Firefox - if it is comma decimal, no values passed in console! Also includes red color border which can be easily removed in style.

Comment: You should use dot(.) instead of comma(,)

Comment: Yes, but in Europe many are using comma. Chrome accepts comma and save it as a point decimal. Could we use pattern in Vue html (pattern="[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?")

Comment: It's firefox issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976393/html5-input-type-number-not-working-in-firefox. You need to handle user input manually.