# Firefox validation not stop user invalid input to be typed

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firefox

i'm working on an Angular6 project, i have an input field that is numeric, on chrome when i digit a letter inside it the letter is not insert. On firefox instead i can write letter inside. the validation work but only blocking the submit of the form. Form use Template validation.

i've tried to use pattern and ngOnChange.

```
<form name="form" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<!--other inputs-->
<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="number" required pattern="[0-9]*" 
 (ngModelChange)="validate($event)"/>
</form>
```

```js
 validate(el){
 console.log(el);// print actual number or null.
}
```

i want to stop invalid input while typed not later in firefox as on chrome already do. at the moment validation work but prevent typing only on chrome.

Comment: The type=number attribute is currently not supported in firefox, check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976393/html5-input-type-number-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to do something like this:

`<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="number" required pattern="[0-9]*" 
 (ngModelChange)="validate($event)" (keydown)="checkIfNumberTyped($event)"/>`

...combined with a matching method like this:

```
checkIfNumberTyped(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    if (event.keyCode === 229 && event.key === 'Unidentified') {
      // This kind of keyboard filtering won't work for some Android devices.
      // Give up trying to filter, or an Android user might not be able to
      // type anything at all.
      return true;
    }
    else if (event.key.length > 1 || event.altKey || event.ctrlKey ||
             event.metaKey || ('0' <= event.key && event.key <= '9') {
      return true;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Sorry I don't remember all of the exact logic that needs to go here off the top of my head. I'll update later if I can, but hopefully this points you in the right direction for now...

UPDATED: I found the code I'd written for this sort of thing before, and updated my answer.

Comment: i've change the code like this.
`code`
  validate(ev : KeyboardEvent) {
      if (ev.keyCode >= 48 && ev.keyCode <= 57 || // all digit
      (ev.key === "ArrowUp" || ev.key === "ArrowDown" )) {
        console.log("is digit "+ev.key);
      }
      else{
        console.log("is not a digit");
        ev.preventDefault(); // should stop event propagation.

      }
  }`code`
but ev.preventDefault() not stop  input to be typed

Answer (score 0):

i've change the code like this.

````
  validate(ev : KeyboardEvent) {
      if (ev.keyCode >= 48 && ev.keyCode <= 57 || // all digit
      (ev.key === "ArrowUp" || ev.key === "ArrowDown" )) {
        console.log("is digit "+ev.key);
      }
      else{
        console.log("is not a digit");
        ev.preventDefault(); // should stop event propagation.
ev.stopPropagation();
      }
  }```
but ev.preventDefault() not stop  input to be typed
````